# How to perform indexing a pdf document in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf

I have a pdf document, I want to fetch some random words from that pdf and save it(indexing/tagging). Then I use those words as searchable tags for that pdf document. Please note I cannot directly use the pdf document to search for a word, I have to relay on the tags created for that document. 
Is there any library which will fetch me those words from a pdf? This is needed for my Mac application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [Spotlight Query](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/SpotlightQuery.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001841) or open the PDF with [PDFKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html) and [search manually](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks/PDFKit_Prog_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH202-SW4).

*Note: I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by "I want to fetch...words from that PDF" and "I cannot directly use the pdf document to search for a word" ... the two seem to be mutually exclusive.*

**Update**

You keep saying "random words" ... do you literally mean you want to a) select words at random from the document to use as tags, b) check to see if any words from a pre-existing list are in the document, or c) look for "any important and interesting words"?

If you mean "c", then use [SearchKit to build the index in memory](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SearchKitConcepts/searchKit_tasks/searchKit_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001071-CH204-SW3).

Comment: I have to fetch some random words from pdf and use them as tags for that document. I will send these words as tags for the pdf to server. Next when a client want to search for a document, when he enters a word, i have to send that word to server which will search for this word in tags of all pdf document. This is the requirement. But i am confused on how to get the random words out of pdf document. Is there anything ready to do this or i have do write my own algorithm to do this.